# Laravel eloquent seems weird showing "[key] is null and [key] is not null" in SQL query

Tags: laravel, eloquent, lumen

I'm sorry I'm still new with Laravel/Lumen and I'm having an issue with table relationships.

This is the error that I keep on receiving.

> "message": "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'clients.client_project_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from
>   `clients` where `clients`.`client_project_id` is null and
>   `clients`.`client_project_id` is not null)",

If you noticed, the SQL query contains a weird where condition and I don't know where in the code is the problem.

I need your expertise on how to resolve this. If you need other info, please do inform me.

[Additional Info]

**MIGRATION FILES**

```
class CreateClientProjectAssignmentTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('client_project', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('project_key', 50);
            $table->integer('client_project_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('client_project_id')
                  ->references('id')
                  ->on('clients')
                  ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('client_project_assignment');
    }
}


class CreateClientsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->string('last_name', 50);
            $table->string('first_name', 50);
            $table->string('email_address', 50);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('clients');
    }
}
```

**SEEDER FILES**

```
class ClientProjectTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->loadDefaultProjects();
    }

    /**
     * Load default projects
     */
    private function loadDefaultProjects()
    {
        $projects = [
            [
                'project_key'    => 'PRJ',
                'client_project_id'     => 1
            ]
        ];

        foreach ($projects as $project) {
            $obj = new ClientProject;
            $obj->fill($project);
            $obj->save();
        }
    }
}

class ClientTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->loadDefaultClients();
    }

    /**
     * Load default clients
     */
    private function loadDefaultClients()
    {
        $clients = [
            [
                'last_name'     => 'First',
                'first_name'    => 'Client',
                'email_address' => 'c.first@sample.com',
            ],
            [
                'last_name'     => 'Second',
                'first_name'    => 'Client',
                'email_address' => 'c.second@sample.com',
            ]
        ];

        foreach ($clients as $client) {
            $obj = new Client;
            $obj->fill($client);
            $obj->save();
        }
    }
}
```

**MODELS**

```
class ClientProject extends AbstractCrudModel
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected $table = 'client_project';

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected $fillable = ['project_key', 'client_project_id'];

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected $hidden = ['updated_at'];

    /**
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function clients()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Client::class);
    }
}

class Client extends AbstractCrudModel
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected $table = 'clients';

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected $hidden = ['updated_at'];

    /**
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\ClientProject');
    }
}
```

**REPOSITORY**

```
class ClientProjectRepository extends AbstractCrudRepository
{
    public function __construct(ClientProject $model)
    {
        $this->setModel($model);
    }

    public function getClients($project)
    {
        $this->model()::find(1)->clients()->get();
    }
}
```

What I'm expecting:

I should be able to retrieve project whose id is 1 and the client's info for that particular project.

Comment: you should show the code.

Comment: show your migration file and your model file and tell us what are you trying

Comment: @TecBeast I've included the code showing the migration, seeder, model and repository files.

Comment: @aaron0207 I've included the code showing the migration, seeder, model and repository files.

Comment: IMO you are making a mistake. You are setting a relation as 1 to 1 (1 project have a client) and then trying to retrieve it as 1 to N (1 project have many clients)

Comment: @aaron0207 which part should I change? I think I'm expecting for the 1 to N relationship

Comment: @Steven oh you are right I missunderstood

Comment: @aaron0207 What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You try to get the Clients that belong to ClientProject. This relation is not setup in your migration. Laravel tries to find the clients with an client_project_id that relates to the ClientProject id. You need to add this migration to client_projects.

`$table->integer('client_project_id')->unsigned();`

Comment: isn't client_id not enough? the client_id in client_projects table is the foreign key for the id in clients table

Comment: then you need to look in to relations with belongsToMany. For a belongsTo relation you need the id of the belonging model to be that model itself.

Comment: Ya, I guess I should use belongstoMany.

"For a belongsTo relation you need the id of the belonging model to be that model itself" - I'm sorry but what do you mean by this?

Comment: belongsTo requires you to have the <model>_id on the model with the belongsTo function itself.

Comment: But it is still not working. I've already changed column name from client_id to client_project_id in client_projects table and changed belongsTo to belongsToMany.

Comment: I've noticed that client_project_id is searched from clients table and not in client_project table. What probably is the cause?